# Difference between document.write(HTML) and document.documentElement.innerHTML= HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the document.write( HTML ) to change a document html and it re-renders the page by itself, which is exactly what I want, but it does not show the same behavior on IE, as following:

```
 document.open();
 document.write(<HTML>);
 document.close();
```

So I tried the following :

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML  = <HTML>;
```

But it did not render the page unless I refresh it.

So what is the difference between them, and what is the best way to change the document content and re-render it?

Comment: @andrusieczko I think this is just an example placeholder ...

Comment: A good answer would probably need to be rather long and detailed. Maybe you should describe what you want, instead of posing a theoretical question. Exactly how do you want to change a document? Presumably adding something specified with an HTML fragment (a real example would be more useful than a dummy notation like `<HTML>`), but *where*? And why would you start *creating* a new document with the `open()` method if you actually want to *change* a document?

Comment: Two obvious differences: `.write()` requires doctype declaration and `<html>` tags whereas `innerHTML` wants head and body only; and when only changing the document's `innerHTML` then all the scripts on the page continue running.

Comment: How does `document.documentElement.innerHTML  = <HTML>` make any sense? That produces `<html><HTML></html>`

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is not a good practice - [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

second approach should work. can you put that on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?
anyway, it is not a good approach (unless you got the html as a string from ajax or similar)

[The best approach is to do DOM manipulation.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp)

**Changes in DOM should be immediate. You should not need to refresh it.**